# React onClick Event in Functional Component

Tags: reactjs, onclick, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I try to add an onClick event, that would show/hide a div in my functional component, can you please help why it doesn't work?

```
export default function OnClickFunctionalComponent (){

    const [showStatements, setShowStatements] = useState(false);
    const onClick = () => setShowStatements(true)

    return(
        <Button onClick={onClick}> Show All</Button>

        { showStatements ? <AllStatements /> : null }
    )
}

const AllStatements = () => (
    <div>
        Some Results
    </div>
)
```

do I use the useState hook incorrectly?

Comment: You defined `AllStatements`, but it doesn't return anything. But I would do it other way. I will edit your code and post it below.

Comment: You need to wrap return into a container (div or fragment) you can't return several elements. Do you want to toggle it (show and hide) or just show?

Comment: I want to toggle.

Comment: to toggle try `setShowStatements((s) => !s)`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return multiple elements in react. It may contain only **one** parent element.

```
import React from 'react'

export default function OnClickFunctionalComponent () {
    const [showStatements, setShowStatements] = React.useState(false);
    const onClick = () => setShowStatements(true)

    let allStatements
    if (showStatements) {
        allStatements = <div>Some Results</div>
    }

    return(
        <div>
            <button onClick={onClick}> Show All</button>

              { allStatements }
        </div>
    )
}
```

Of course you can put the conditional rendering inside elements, but I prefer this way since it looks more clear.

For more info read this page: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Also `Button` doesn't exists unless you have created a component called Button. In HTML it's written in lowercase, so `button`.

Comment: sorry, yes I Button is created, it is not the problem. Now the error message tells:React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by Query... do you have any idea, why?

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you want to toggle the div, right? You are almost there, the problem is that you are setting `showStatements` always to `true` when you click the button. To toggle, you should negate the value that was in the state before. Something like this should work:

```
const onClick = () => setShowStatements(prevShow => !prevShow)
```

I use the callback because something might not work if you access directly the previous value that was in the state.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code in arrow function like this and also binded inside a react fragment so that we can return multiple elements in react and its working fine

```
import { useState } from "react";

const  App = () => {

const [showStatements, setShowStatements] = useState(false);

const onClick = () => setShowStatements(toggle => !toggle)

return(
   <>
     <button onClick={onClick}> Show All</button>
     { showStatements ? <AllStatements /> : null }
  </>
)
```

}

```
const AllStatements = () => (
  <div>
      Some Results
  </div>
```

)

```
export default App;
```

Comment: Seems correct solutions